# Change select based on previous selection

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

I have two select, the first is visibile and the user can choose an option.
The second select is hidden and I need to set a value based on the first choose.

The second select is already populated and I need to select an option.

Let's suppose that I have this:

```
<li class="select-province-form">
   <select name="select1">
       <option value="A">AA</option>
       <option value="B">BB</option>
       <option value="C">CC</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

This the second:

```
<li class="select-regioni-form">
    <select name="select2">
        <option value="AA">AAAA</option>
        <option value="BB">BBBB</option>
        <option value="CC">CCCC</option>
    </select>
</li>
```

Now I have this code:

```
$(document.body).on('change',"li.select-province-form select",function (e) {
        var regione = '';
        var selectedProv = this.value;
        $.each( SpElencoRegioni[0], function( key, val ) {

            if(key == selectedProv){
                regione = val;
               $('li.select-regioni-form select').val(regione);
                break;
            }
        });

    });
```

SpElencoRegioni:

```
var SpElencoRegioni = [{"A":"AA","B":"BB","C":"CC"}];
```

The problem is that in the second select nothing happen.

Comment: If `SpElencoRegioni` is *really* an actual JSON (i.e. a string) you should parse it first.

Comment: I have edited the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error in your script. You can't `break` if you're not inside a cycle, and jQuery's `each` is not a cycle, it's a method.

To break from it you should `return false`.

**EDIT:**

In the comments you say it doesn't work, but the snippet below (where I just changed the order of the code and put the `return false` I mentioned in the answer) begs to differ :)

Some reasons this doesn't work is because you either didn't import jQuery correctly or `SpElencoRegioni` is not available in the callback's scope or your DOM structure doesn't reflect the selectors you're using in your JS code. Please check.

```js
var SpElencoRegioni = [{"A":"AA","B":"BB","C":"CC"}];

$(document.body).on('change',"li.select-province-form select",function (e) {
    var regione = '';
    var selectedProv = this.value;
    $.each( SpElencoRegioni[0], function( key, val ) {

        if(key == selectedProv){
            regione = val;
           $('li.select-regioni-form select').val(regione);
           return false;
        }
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="select-province-form">
       <select name="select1">
           <option value="A">AA</option>
           <option value="B">BB</option>
           <option value="C">CC</option>
        </select>
    </li>


    <li class="select-regioni-form">
        <select name="select2">
            <option value="AA">AAAA</option>
            <option value="BB">BBBB</option>
            <option value="CC">CCCC</option>
        </select>
    </li>
```

Comment: Thanks Federico, i have removed the break but the second select is not updated anyway